# How to get id element of the list?

Tags: 2013, list-item

**Sharepoint 2013
How to recover a document library element id?**

```
var file;
var fileCreateInfo;

$(document).ready(function()  
{
    fileInput = $("#getFile");  
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', registerClick);  
});  

function registerClick()  
{  
    //Register File Upload Click Event  
    $("#addFileButton").click(CreateFile);  
}

function CreateFile()
{
    // Ensure the HTML5 FileReader API is supported
    if (window.FileReader)
    {
        input = document.getElementById("getFile");

        if (input)
        {
            file = input.files[0];
            fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = receivedBinary;
            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("The HTML5 FileSystem APIs are not fully supported in this browser.");
    }
}

// Callback function for onload event of FileReader
function receivedBinary()
{

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('http://servicosda.metroweb.sp.gov.br//');
    this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    clientContext.load(this.oWebsite); 
    var list = this.oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("Cadastro de Serviços da GOP"); 

    fileCreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
    fileCreateInfo.set_url(file.name);
    fileCreateInfo.set_overwrite(true);
    fileCreateInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());

    // Read the binary contents of the base 64 data URL into a Uint8Array
    // Append the contents of this array to the SP.FileCreationInformation
    var arr = convertDataURIToBinary(this.result);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    {
        fileCreateInfo.get_content().append(arr[i]);
    }

    // Upload the file to the root folder of the document library
    this.newFile = list.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);

    clientContext.load(this.newFile,f => f.ListItemAllFields);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    //Print List Item Id
    Console.WriteLine("List Item Id: {0}", this.newFile.ListItemAllFields.Id);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
}

function onSuccess()
{
    // File successfully uploaded
    alert("Success!");

}

function onFailure()
{
    // Error occurred
    alert("Request failed: " + arguments[1].get_message());
    console.log("Request failed: " + arguments[1].get_message());
}

// Utility function to remove base64 URL prefix and store base64-encoded string in a Uint8Array
// Courtesy: https://gist.github.com/borismus/1032746
function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI)
{
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
    var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
    var raw = window.atob(base64);
    var rawLength = raw.length;
    var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

    for (i = 0; i < rawLength; i++)
    {
        array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Could you please write a few lines explaining your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2) article to know how to upload a file and retrieve the ID for corresponding ListItem. Please find below the code referred from the same article:

```
'use strict';
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // Check for FileReader API (HTML5) support.
    if (!window.FileReader) {
        alert('This browser does not support the FileReader API.');
    }
});
// Upload the file.
// You can upload files up to 2 GB with the REST API.
function uploadFile() {
    // Define the folder path for this example.
    var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = '/shared documents';
    // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
    var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
    var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();
    // Get the server URL.
    var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    var getFile = getFileBuffer();
    getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {
        // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
        var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer);
        addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {
            // Get the list item that corresponds to the uploaded file.
            var getItem = getListItem(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
            getItem.done(function (listItem, status, xhr) {
                // Change the display name and title of the list item.
                var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata);
                changeItem.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                    alert('file uploaded and updated');
                });
                changeItem.fail(onError);
            });
            getItem.fail(onError);
        });
        addFile.fail(onError);
    });
    getFile.fail(onError);
    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    function getFileBuffer() {
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e.target.error);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
        return deferred.promise();
    }
    // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
    function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {
        // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
        var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
        var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];
        // Construct the endpoint.
        var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
                serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);
        // Send the request and return the response.
        // This call returns the SharePoint file.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
            }
        });
    }
    // Get the list item that corresponds to the file by calling the file's ListItemAllFields property.
    function getListItem(fileListItemUri) {
        // Send the request and return the response.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: fileListItemUri,
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
        });
    }
    // Change the display name and title of the list item.
    function updateListItem(itemMetadata) {
        // Define the list item changes. Use the FileLeafRef property to change the display name. 
        // For simplicity, also use the name as the title. 
        // The example gets the list item type from the item's metadata, but you can also get it from the
        // ListItemEntityTypeFullName property of the list.
        var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}'}}",
            itemMetadata.type, newName, newName);
        // Send the request and return the promise.
        // This call does not return response content from the server.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: itemMetadata.uri,
            type: "POST",
            data: body,
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-length": body.length,
                "IF-MATCH": itemMetadata.etag,
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
            }
        });
    }
}
// Display error messages. 
function onError(error) {
    alert(error.responseText);
}
```